# When do I have to respect the $C$ constant and when can I combine?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, constants

## Question

Verify that the given two-parameter family of functions is the general solution of the non-homogeneous differential equation on the indicated interval.

$$
y''-4y'+4y = 2e^{2x}+4x-12
$$
$$
y=C_1e^{2x}+C_2xe^{2x}+x^2e^{2x}+x-2; (-\infty,\infty)
$$

I solved it to the point where, after plugging in my $y''$ I get this on the left side of the top equation:

$$
-4C_1e^{2x}-4C_2xe^{2x}-4x^2e^{2x}+2e^{2x}-4
$$

I'm not 100% positive if the above is correct but my curiosity compulsed me to come here and ask this question: Could I combine the $C_1$ and $C_2$ **if they happened to have the same $x$ terms?** For example, let's say they read $-4C_1xe^{2x}$ and $-4C_2xe^{2x}$. Would this be equal to $-8Cxe^{2x}$? When do I have to respect the difference in $C$'s and when not?

Comment: Plug in some (distinct) values for $C_1$ and $C_2$. Are there any arithmetic laws you could apply if you knew they were coefficients for the same $x$ term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution of a linear ODE can be written as
$$
y=y_{h}+y{c}
$$
where $y_{h}$ stands for the homogeneous solution and $y_{c}$ is the complementary particular solution. In your case, the ODE
$$
y''-4y'+4y=0
$$
has homogeneous solutions $c_{1}e^{2x}$ and $c_{2}xe^{2x}$.

You can easily verify that $x^2e^{2x}+x-2$ is particular solution for
$$
y''-4y'+4y = 2e^{2x}+4x-12
$$
With that you are done. $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ will be determined from the appropriate initial conditions. I hope that helps.

Comment: You make it seem so simple...I'm trying to fully wrap my head around this. So you're saying that in order to verify that the given $y=C_1e^{2x}$... is a solution all you have to do is to consider that the given nonhomogeneous equation can be expressed in terms of its homogeneous and particular solutions, then verify those individually? Is accurate to say that **all** nonhomogeneous differential equations can be split like that?

Comment: yes that is right. However this approach only works for linear differential equations. Nonlinear ODE's, for example, won't satisfy this.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is fine. In general, you can always define $C_3=f(C_1,C_2)$ as long as doing so eliminates either $C_1$ or $C_2$ from the equation. While it is still technically correct otherwise, you wind up with three constants which are then no longer arbitrary, which only serves to make the solution more confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your answer. Are you saying that I can combine them in $C$ simply because it removes them from the problem? If that's true, then we do we even write $C_1$ and $C_2$ in the first place?

Comment: $C_1$ and $C_2$ should be coefficients of two linearly independent solutions of a differential equation. If your two solutions are $C_1xe^{2x}$ and $C_2xe^{2x}$, then they are not linearly independent, so there are more solutions out there. Sometimes in calculating a particular solutions, you end up with something that looks like a term in the homogeneous solution. In this case, it is helpful to lump this term in the particular solution with the homogeneous solution.